# Connect to remote postgresql server on amazon ec2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postgresql-9.1

I started an amazon ec2 instance, and installed postgresql 9.1 over it. I then went to the 
Security Group: quicklaunch-1`(there was one more`default` which i did not change) and opened the 5432 TCP Port, the table looks like this:

```
(Service)   Source  Action
22        0.0.0.0/0         Delete
5432      0.0.0.0/32    Delete
5433      0.0.0.0/32    Delete
6432      0.0.0.0/32    Delete
```

I have created a database  and user . 
My `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` looks like this:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    db_name         user_name       0.0.0.0/0               md5

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

and **/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf** looks like this:

```
# - Connection Settings -
listen_addresses = '*'
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
```

I then try to connect on to the remote machine as follows:

```
psql -h ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com -d <database_name> -U <username>
```

where **ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com** is my **Public DNS**.

The above command does not result in any connection, how can i connect?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this table:

```
5432      0.0.0.0/32    Delete
5433      0.0.0.0/32    Delete
6432      0.0.0.0/32    Delete
```

the CIDRs look like you're not allowing any IP in. Shouldn't they be `0.0.0.0/0` instead, like what you have for port 22 (ssh)?

Comment: what is the difference between port 32 and port 0.

Comment: @whatf: `32` is not a port number, it's the prefix size in [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation). `0.0.0.0/0` means allowing connections from any address. `5432` is the port number.

Comment: OMG! I've been looking for this answer this entire two-day weekend! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6):

I Found the resolution to this problem.
Two things are required.

1. Use a text editor to modify pg_hba.conf.
   Locate the line host    all             all             127.0.0.1/0               md5.
   Immediately below it, add this new line: host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
2. Editing the PostgreSQL postgresql.conf file:

   Use a text editor to modify postgresql.conf.
   Locate the line that starts with #listen_addresses = 'localhost'.
   Uncomment the line by deleting the #, and change localhost to `*`.
   The line should now look like this: `listen_addresses = '*'`                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;.

Now Just restart your postgres service and it will connect

Comment: You probably need to enable SSL/TLS if you go with this option.

Comment: If you want to allow all addresses to access your database, don't use `listen_addresses = ''` on Postgres9.5, use `listen_addresses = '*'` (note the asterisk)

Answer (score -1):

your psql command needs a -W option added, which allows you to enter a password for the db user and a -p option followed by the postgres port number (5432 per default)

cheers!