# cannot connect to PostgreSQL DB running on EC2 instance

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, table-plus

I have a simple PostgreSQL DB running on an EC2 instance.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-xx:~$ service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2020-06-19 14:04:12 UTC; 7h ago
 Main PID: 11065 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Jun 19 14:04:12 ip-172-31-38-xx systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jun 19 14:04:12 ip-172-31-38-xx systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-xx:~$ psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql (10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SELECT *
postgres-# FROM pg_settings
postgres-# WHERE name = 'port';
 name | setting | unit |                       category                       |                short_desc                | extra_desc |  context   | vartype |       source       | min_val | max_val | enumvals | boot_val | reset_val |               sourcefile                | sourceline | pending_restart
------+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+--------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+------------+-----------------
 port | 5432    |      | Connections and Authentication / Connection Settings | Sets the TCP port the server listens on. |            | postmaster | integer | configuration file | 1       | 65535   |          | 5432     | 5432      | /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf |         63 | f
(1 row)
```

The only Security Group that is associated with this EC2 instance has inbound rules wide open:

```
5432, TCP, 0.0.0.0/0
```

But when I use a client to connect to this DB with the correct hostname (public IP/DNS), port number, DB name, user name and password typed in, it always says:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused, is the server running on host "ec2-dns.com(172.public.ip)" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to an IP that starts with 172.something?  That's the internal IP, not the external one.

Comment: No, I used its public IP and/or DNS, no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right, I've figured it out from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413170/4117496)

Two things I did to enable myself to connect (exactly from the link above, I'm duplicating it here for convenience):

1. open this file: `sudo vi /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf`

immediately below this line:

`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5`

added this line:

`host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5`

2. open this file: `sudo vi /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`

find a line that starts with this:
`#listen_addresses = 'localhost'`

Uncomment the line by deleting the #, and change 'localhost' to '*'.

The line should now look like this:

`listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;.`

then restart your service:

`sudo service postgresql restart`

then you should be able to connect to your DB via a SQL client.

Comment: While this answer includes the necessary steps, opening up to all addresses is quite insecure. `listen_addresses` doesn't affect what addresses to listen to, so that is ok, but in `pg_hba.conf`, you should specify an address/range. Also, `pg_hba.conf` can be in different places, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/256711/109484).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure PostgreSQL is listening on the IP address and Port number that you are using as host and port parameters. Try by modifying your postgresql.conf file and restarting the server.

```sh
   sudo nano /etc/postgresql/{YOUR_POSTGRES_VERSION}/main/postgresql.conf
```

Now go on and find the connection settings and update the following values.

```
   listen_addresses = {YOUR_IP_ADDRESS}
   port = {YOUR_PORT_NUMBER}
```

Now save the file and restart postgresl server:

```sh
   sudo systemctl restart postgres
```

Checkout documentation
[here:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS)