# Can't connect to Postgres using pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, pgadmin

I am trying to connect to my postgres database which is install on AWS EC2 instance.

I have installed pgadmin3 on my local ubuntu machine and I am trying to connect my postgres but I am getting error:

```
 reports could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "myip" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

On aws I have open port 5432.

I edited my postgresql.conf and I added :

```
 listen_addresses = '*'
```

and inside pg_hba.conf I added this:

```
host    all         all         192.168.1.0/24        md5
```

But now I am getting this error:

```
 FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "myip", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL on FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "myip", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off getting this error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by adding this line to postgresql.conf :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

file location of postgresql.conf is:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf
```

And I added this line in file pg_hba.conf:

```
 # IPv4 local connections:
 host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
 host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

And restarted postgres service using:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit `postgresql.conf` file and change line with 'listen_addresses'.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Then you have edit `pg_hba.conf` file, too. In this file you have set, from which computers you can connect to this server and what method of authentication you can use. Usually you will need similar line:

```
host    all         all         192.168.1.0/24        md5
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu where is the location of that file

Comment: Look in this location : /etc/postgresql/9.3/main. Replace 9.3 with the version you installed

Comment: this file pg_hba.conf is empty

Comment: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "myip", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL on FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "myip", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off  getting this error

Comment: Have a look at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14545298/1225070