# Unable to connect to an postgresql ec2 instance from pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance and then installed postgresql (version 11) and timescaledb in it. My security group looks as follows:

[image]

As of now, I have enabled this instance for all the IP addresses.

My `/etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf` looks like this:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5 #ipv4 range
host    all             all             ::0/0                   md5 #ipv6 range
host    all             all             all                     md5 #all ip
```

and the `/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf` looks like this:

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
```

Then, I try to connect to the database via Pgadmin4 using the `Public DNS(IPv4)`:`ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

[image]

After I enter the username and password, it throws the following error:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com" (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I had a look at the following post and followed all the instructions, but to no avail:

1. [connect-to-remote-postgresql-server-on-amazon-ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545298/connect-to-remote-postgresql-server-on-amazon-ec2)

Can anyone please help me out with this?

**Edit 1**

When I do:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

I get:

```
[....] Restarting postgresql (via systemctl): postgresql.service==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'postgresql.service'.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password:
```

I don't know what password to enter here so that the postgresql can get restarted

Comment: Did you restart the database after changing postgresql.conf?  If so, did it actually start?  If you ssh to the machine, can you connect with `psql`?

Comment: @jjanes Hey, I edited my question with the restart part. Could you  please have a look at it?

Comment: You were right, @jjanes. The problem was in restarting the db. I did: `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart` and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @jjanes in the comments, I had to restart the postgresql inorder to access it.

Doing

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

was throwing an error (as shown in the question) that's why I had to use

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

in order to grant the root access.

Once the db was restarted, I tried connecting to the ec2 instance again via pgadmin4, and this time it worked.